# What do I need to consider in terms of licensing if I make videos showing Stack Exchange posts?

Tags: support, review, legal, licensing

I'm considering making voiced-over videos of myself working the review queues (for entertainment, to keep my concentration sharp, and maybe to help others). Of course, the posts in the review queues would be visible in the videos, and by the [CC-BY-SA](https://creativecommons.org/licenses/by-sa/3.0/) license, I'd need to show the author's name and link to it. Of course, the author's name would be shown with every post. The trick is linking to the posts, since there would be dozens (well, at least 20) shown.

There are several specific questions involved here:

- Would the review task URL shown in the browser's address bar be sufficient attribution, or would I need to produce a list of posts shown, a link to them, *and* a link to the user?
- How well would I need to organize that list, and where would I put it (e.g. right in the video description, or in a text file linked in the description)?
- If I edit the reviewed posts, would Stack Exchange's revision history and/or the previous edition shown in the video be sufficient to satisfy the "indicate changes made" part of the license?
- Do I need to make some spiel at the beginning of the videos to indicate that I didn't make the content shown and that I'm not affiliated with Stack Exchange?

Comment: Sounds like fair use that doesn't require anything at all, but ianal

Comment: I'm tempted to say that as long as the visibility of the URL is the same as the visibility of the post, it's fine... but it occurs to me that there's an edge case that's problematic. Posts that have been deleted since you reviewed them (in some cases, *because* you reviewed them) would not generally be accessible through their /review/ URL. (Just tested in a private window to be sure.)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Just to be on the safe side, I spent a bit of time rigging up an eldritch horror composed of a Chrome extension that communicates with an ASP.NET server running on `localhost`. Every time the address bar's text changes to a `/review/` URL, the extension pokes the server, which downloads the page, runs the JavaScript (in an embedded Internet Explorer in the server process), and scrapes the relevant links, usernames, and titles. At the end of the session, the server spits out an HTML document that, when distributed with such a video, satisfies the guidelines in [Attribution Required](https://blog.stackoverflow.com/2009/06/attribution-required/).

The code is [available on GitHub](https://github.com/Fleex255/StackReviewAttrib).

The video playlist is now [visible on YouTube](https://www.youtube.com/playlist?list=PL-BuW7CehqurmdAT8LdIOUmB3hUwa19sB).