# Someone copy-pasted my Database Administrators Stack Exchange site question on YouTube

Tags: discussion, copyright, copyright-infringement, youtube

I asked a question on the *[Database Administrators](https://dba.stackexchange.com/tour)* Stack Exchange site a few days back:

[MySQL 8 query doesn't prefer index with higher cardinality](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/333683/mysql-8-query-doesnt-prefer-index-with-higher-cardinality)

Today, I randomly found this video on YouTube.

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=0gqNmz9W-7s

Someone just copied my question to his YouTube video, without adding any additional answer or comments. That's just lazy content generation.

Is that allowed? Can I or should I do anything about it? I especially don't want my name being associated with his video.

He has referenced some Meta Stack Exchange link, but that doesn't work either.

Comment: In the description of the linked video there is attribution for the content. Once you've made a post on SE, anyone can use it so long as they attribute it, so I'm not sure I see the problem here.

Comment: " I especially don't want my name being associated with his video." Your question on stackexchange is licensed under CC BY-SA 4.0, they *have* to state your name, otherwise they would violate the license. If you would release your question under an additional license without this requirement, maybe you could ask the video creator to remove your name.

Comment: Note that per CC BY SA 4.0, you can request that your name be removed from that video, and the author is obligated to do so "to the extent reasonably practicable."

Comment: I am fairly sure these people are planning to monetize their videos in the future, if not already. It just seemed illogical that he'd be allowed to just copy-paste (and he doesn't even do a good job), but if it is as per the license, then I guess I can't do anything. I hope the license prevents him from monetizing at least.

Comment: @ShahidThaika The license does not prevent monetization. However, I see an interesting question. The CC BY-SA license requires that the transformation is released under the same license as the original work. I would take that to mean the video - the images (of the CC BY-SA text) and the music - would need to be CC BY-SA. However, it's not clear if he is allowed to release the music under that license. And, since YouTube doesn't allow selecting CC BY-SA as a license (it only allows for CC BY), I would expect a clear statement that the video is available CC BY-SA for others to share and remix.

Comment: Yam, learning that a *video of scrolling over badly rendered text* is preferred by some people over actually accessing *that text itself* - that’s harsh.

Comment: Looks like *technically* they fail to adhere to large parts of the license. "give appropriate credit" isn't really given since it's not clear which parts are from whom. The required "link to the license" is broken. "indicate if changes were made" isn't satisfied either. "not in any way that suggests the licensor endorses you or your use" is rather questionable with the "Thanks to all those great people for their contributions" line, implying people contributed *to the video*. Plus the "under the same license as the original" seems to be missed as well.

Comment: In light of @MisterMiyagi's comments, I'd point out [the official guidance for what to do when another site is failing to follow the license terms](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/200178/572). However, that guidance is almost 2 years old and some more recent comments in other contexts may raise questions about its accuracy. This is a good opportunity for the company to revisit this guidance, perhaps even codifying it into a Help Center article instead of a Meta question.

Comment: @ThomasOwens: I think part of the reason it's remained a Meta post and not a Help Center page is that the company can't legally require you to do anything about other sites rehosting content from SO/SE, and they're wary that having an official Help Center page saying what to do could be construed as "legal advice" or something. It's mostly just general guidance on what actions folks can choose to take themselves.

Comment: @V2Blast Perhaps. But a disclaimer that it's not legal advice would be nice. Regardless, I don't think that the old guidance is still valid today.

Comment: @MisterMiyagi - half of YouTube is watching someone fumble through an explanation it would be quicker & easier to read. I fear for the future of humanity. If global warming doesn't get us, stupidity in the form of 'bite-sized instant gratification' will.

Comment: yep. pretty sure this is allowed by CC-BY-SA. I've seen at least two of my posts on this channel in the past as well :P

Comment: @Glorfindel It's unclear to me what's desired from staff here. There's already guidance as to what courses of action are available to the user in the FAQ: "[A site (or scraper) is copying content from Stack Exchange. What should I do?](/q/200177/271271)". There's no indication that the guidance should be changed. If what's desired is an update from staff to that guidance, then it would be much better to have a question that specifically requests that. If I was a member of staff looking at this, I'd wonder what was desired, other than closing as a duplicate of that FAQ.

Comment: "and the author is obligated to do so "to the extent reasonably practicable."" It seems worth noting that the channel in question has put up more than **twenty-seven thousand** videos in a bit over a year, all following an identical format. I have no idea what the clips of walking through the forest, or the thumbnails, are intended to provide. I've also seen this channel mentioned in SO chat before.

Comment: @Makyen a user flagged it for [tag:status-review] with a plausible reason. If staff decides to close it as a duplicate, that's fine with me (and perhaps also with the flagger).

Comment: I've closed this as a duplicate because _for this specific incident_ the answer is already elsewhere. For the reason why this post was escalated: feel free to create a separate question related specifically to whether or not the current guidelines need revising, and escalate _that one_ instead, so we can keep the conversation focused ;)

Comment: There must also be a lot more specific MSE question. This particular way of using Stack Exchange content on YouTube has been up before. (In general, the attribution is ***never*** correct, even if there is an attempt.)

Comment: Related: *[What do I need to consider in terms of licensing if I make videos showing Stack Exchange posts?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/276019/what-do-i-need-to-consider-in-terms-of-licensing-if-i-make-videos-showing-stack/279894#279894)* and *[Can I make a YouTube video adapting Stack Overflow content?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/372440/can-i-make-a-youtube-video-adapting-stack-overflow-content)*

Comment: It was probably this one: *[YouTube channel scraping Q&A from Stack Exchange](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/386545/youtube-channel-scraping-qa-from-stack-exchange)*. Or maybe *[This YouTube channel is creating videos based on SO questions. Is this ok?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/381384/)*

Comment: see also https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/396232/997587

Answer (score 1):

Stack Exchange content is freely licensed under a Creative Commons license, so they can use your answer as long as attribution is done and the license is not changed.

Did they give attribution to your answer? If not, it’s under violation of the license.